# Which is an easiest way to implement in Dart the console application with a subcommands?

Tags: command-line, console, dart

The `pub` package manager has a lot of commands and it written in the Dart language.

Is this possible implement the same functionality (subcommands) without too much effort?

Are there any library with which you can speed up the development of various commands and options in console application?

Well, for example, I would like to implement a program with the following commands (with options and arguments):

- create project
- create controller
- create view
- create action

How to quickly develop handlers for them?

Answer (score 3):

That's what the [args](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/args) package is for.

Comment: I see you have registered here on a regular basis. Answer all the questions without delay. I believe that the personally you voted on closing this question becaгse you don't have an useful answer. Might be worth to provide an opportunity to others who want to respond?

Comment: Off topic because - `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: You can improve your question and the close vote will be void (needs 5 anyway)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it later.